# ConfigurationChange table not getting data in Log Analytics Workspace for Azure VM with Change Tracking enabled with Azure Monitoring Agent

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am getting pretty annoyed by Azure these days. I am working on a rather generic approach of monitoring VMs in Azure. And I am using the "new" ways of doing it: Data Collection Rules, Azure Monitoring Agent and so on. There are quite some issues but I worked around most of them. But one I did not get solved: Change Tracking!

Goal: I want to know when and which Windows Services were started or stopped and be able to alert on that.

Approach and Progress:

- enabled "Change Tracking" feature on the VM, selected the Azure Monitoring Agent approach and connected it to my (central) Log Analytics workspace
- Azure created a default Data Collection Rule in the resource group of my LAW, it has no visual data sources configured but the VM is connected as a resource
- ChangeTracking extension was installed on the VM (besides Azure Monitoring Agent and the Dependency Agent from VM Insights)
- the JSON view of the data collection rule shows me, that it has configured many configurations

```
"registrySettings": {
    "registryCollectionFrequency": 3000,
    "registryInfo": [
    {
        "name": "Registry_1",
        "enabled": false,
        "recurse": true,
        "description": "",
        "keyName": "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Group Policy\\Scripts\\Startup",
        "valueName": ""
    },
...
...           
"fileSettings": {
    "fileCollectionFrequency": 2700
},
"softwareSettings": {
    "softwareCollectionFrequency": 1800
},
"inventorySettings": {
    "inventoryCollectionFrequency": 36000
},
"servicesSettings": {
    "serviceCollectionFrequency": 1800
}
```

My understanding here is, that service settings are collected every 30 minutes - not great, not terrible. But after hours and many started / stopped services on the VM, the only Change-Tracking related table that gets data ingested in my LAW is "ConfigurationData". But that only shows installed updates and software of my VM. All example queries regarding stopped services leverage a table called "ConfigurationChange" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking/overview-monitoring-agent#support-for-alerts-on-configuration-state). The table shows up in the LAW "Tables" view but it does not receive *any* data. No other table contains those information - even the "Events" table does not. The current limitations do *not* mention the started/stopped services (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking/overview-monitoring-agent#current-limitations).

What am I doing wrong?? How do I get this started/stopped services information into the LAW?

Edit: In the mean time, I got data into the "ConfigurationChange" table. But it only shows installed software. Still not stopped/started services. Any reason for that?
[image: ConfigurationChange table entry for installed security update]

Answer (score 0):

> Goal: I want to know when and which Windows Services were started or stopped and be able to alert on that.

You can also check the **Azure VM Windows Services** and from here also you can generate an alert.

**Select your Azure VM > Change Tracking**

[image]

Another approach to check **VM Windows Services**.

Create a **Data Collection** rule for chekcing all VM Windows Services, See the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-collection-rule-azure-monitor-agent?tabs=portal)

> Note: Make sure that you select all rules with `\system`  to fetch all **Windows Services** in LAW

[image]

Now you can use the below **KQL Query** to check all windows services stopped and started states.

```
ConfigurationChange
| where ConfigChangeType == "WindowsServices"
| project TimeGenerated,Computer,SvcDisplayName,SvcName,SvcState
```

**Output**

[image]

Now if you want to generate the alert when a perticular service state is running, follow the below steps.

```
ConfigurationChange
| where ConfigChangeType == "WindowsServices"
| where SvcName contains "wuauserv"
| where SvcState contains "Running"
| project TimeGenerated,Computer,SvcDisplayName,SvcName,SvcState
```

**Output:**

[image]

Create an **Action Group** like below.

[image]

Create an alert rule as below.

[image]
[image]

Now you will get the alert when a perticular **Windows Service** state is running.

[image]

Refer : [How to monitor Windows Service in Azure VM](https://www.smcculloch.com/monitor-windows-service-azure-vm) for more details about **VM Windows Services** created by @ Scott McCulloch

Comment: The problem is not that I don't know how to define the query. The problem seems to be, that Azure Monitoring Agent does not transfer data about started / stopped services to Log Analytics workspace at all. As I've written, the only data in the table is installed software after many, many manual starts and stops of services on the VM.

Comment: Hi @sebastian87, I have made few changes in the answer, kindly check the same.