# Azure VM alerting for process and services

Tags: azure, monitor, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

All,

I have windows VMs where AMA agent is installed with DCR configuration. How do I report on specific alert on process and service ?

Another requirement is this possible to alert on affected VM with top 10 process output when alert is sent . This helps the person who is going to work on VM to know process status on machine which is consuming most memory or CPU ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have windows VMs where AMA agent is installed with DCR configuration. How do I report on specific alert on process and service ?

If you want to create an alert for a process, follow the steps below.

1. Create a  **Log Analytics Work Space**
2. Create a  **Data Collection Rule**, follow the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-collection-rule-azure-monitor-agent?tabs=portal#create-a-data-collection-rule)

3.Run the following `Kusto Query Language` query to check `VM` processes

**KQL Query:**

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Process" 
| where CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| where CounterValue >= 80
| project InstanceName, CounterValue
```

**Result:**

[image]

For creating an alert for `VM Service` follow my [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75734660/configurationchange-table-not-getting-data-in-log-analytics-workspace-for-azure/75742685#75742685) thread, which is related to creating an alert on a specific service.

> Another requirement is this possible to alert on affected VM with top10 process output when alert is sent . This helps the person who is going to work on VM to know process status on machine which is consuming most memory or CPU ?

Here is the `Log Analytics` query that retrieves the top `10 processes` by `CPU usage`. However, it's not possible to send an alert with the top 10 results directly. Instead, you can use an `Azure Logic App` in conjunction with `Azure Monitor` alerts.

**KQL Query:**

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Process" and CounterName == "% Processor Time"
| summarize avg_CPU = avg(CounterValue) by InstanceName
| top 10 by avg_CPU desc
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Venkat. I saw this thread to enable monitoring of windows services, and tried to enable PerformanceCounter to include /system/process others, but it results in error , since already PerformanceCounter is selected with Vminsights :-

Comment: This is update error :- Error - 'Counter Specifiers' predefined counter categories '\VmInsights\DetailedMetrics' cannot be mixed with other specifiers. Use separate data source for each predefined counter .category

Comment: Similar to what we see in our windows computer to open task manager and see which applications or services are consuming High Memroy and High CPU, so i am looking for both High CPU and Memory alerting.

I tried to run your query for High CPU, however its not giving any results :- 
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Process" | distinct CounterName
| where CounterName == "% Processor Time"

Comment: Under ObjectName = process, only following counterName are available:-

Handle Count
Thread Count
Working Set
Working Set - Private

Comment: My DCR Configuration is set with Performance Counters, Windows Events :-

Comment: Then What query I should run to alert for High Memory and High CPU ?

Another requirement, when this alert fires, I also want to append the top process consuming the High Memory or HIGH CPU.  I read some documentation wherein some workbook and Logic apps being used to send custom payload, but it was not clear

Comment: **PerformanceCounter** is for monitoring `VM Process`, for VM `Windows process` refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75734660/configurationchange-table-not-getting-data-in-log-analytics-workspace-for-azure/75742685#75742685)

Comment: Hi @swadesh, let me know, if you still facing any issue.

Comment: i followed the given link for ConfiguraitonChange table to appear and added the system/process custom performance counters to DCR . But still I don't see the table ConfiguraitonChange  in Log Analytics workspace.

Comment: Have you selected correct Log Analytics workspace while creating DCR?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255674/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-swadesh).